# How to export the treeview class to a different workbook in VBA Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I exported my userform with a treeview to a different workbook, but I get this error:
[image: Error]

I believe because there is no `Treeview` class in the workbook I exported the userform with a treeview as shown in the image:
[image]

However, in the original workbook, there is a `Treeview` class in the workbook as show below:
[image]

I do not understand why it is not present in the other workbook, while it is present in the other. How to export or add the `Treeview` class in my workbook without that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we select the `TreeView` item in the workbook that it is present in we can see that the `TreeView` is a member of the  `MSComctlLib`

[image: MSComctlLib]

Selecting this then shows us that `MSComctlLib` is part of the Library `Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)`

[image: Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)]

Check your references in the VBA editor for the workbook that it is missing in `Tools->References` and make sure that there is a reference to `Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)` selected.

If it is missing select it and the `TreeView` should work